# Coding Offset Grid Columns with SASS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, grid-layout

I am trying to code my own responsive grid system using SASS. Using this simple [Tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-responsive-grid-made-even-better-with-sass--cms-21540) I was able to make a simple grid.

Currently, I am calculating the widths of all the columns according to their media query using this code:

```
@media #{$breakpoint-medium} {
    .wrapper {      
        width: 95%;
        max-width: $grid-max-width;     
        }
    @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {      
        .col-#{$i} {         
            width: 100% / $grid-columns * $i;   
            }           
        }   
    }
```

Where $grid-columns = 12

This works well, however, I'd like to center a block of text that I have designated as 8-columns wide, so I need to push, or offset this column by 2 columns.

I'm new to SASS so I'm still getting my bearings with using math in my CSS and such, but how can I adapt this code so that I can make a similar class, "push-#" that will automatically know to push the content properly?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essentially the same math, you are just applying margin instead of width.

```
@for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {      
    .push-#{$i} {         
        margin-left: 100% / $grid-columns * $i;   
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Steve, much appreciated!